# Query failing while Database is Connected

Tags: php, wamp

I'm trying to run a basic sql query that is failing, even though I can confirm that the database is connected. Using mysql_error() doesn't give an error message. I've been told that it could be an Apache permissions issue, but I'm not seeing that.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
    // 1. Create a database connection
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "moneymouth";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbname);

      // Test if connection succeeded
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . 
            mysqli_connect_error() . 
            " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
        );
    }   
?>  

<?php
    // 2. Perform database query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);
    if (!$result){
        die ("Database query failed.");
        ;
    }
?>
```

Comment: As a pointer your secound mysqli_connect() parameter you have labled $dbname the paramters should be host, username, password, database_name

Comment: The last semicolon is useless: it's not an error, but you can leave it

Comment: Are you sure that you can connect to the database using "localhost"? Check with your hosting provider. Also, do you have any users in your table? Maybe it's running and just doesn't display anything.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks everyone. The problem was the lack of two mysqli_connect() parameters. The other responses were helpful as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are sure about first part 'cause no error form `mysql_error()`?

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db_name");
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

It seems that something is missing.

Second part:

```
<?php
  // 2. Perform database query
  $query = "SELECT * FROM users;";
  $result = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);
  if (!$result){
      die ("Database query failed.");
  }
?>
```

Try to put `;` at the end of query, in some cases is required and if missing it can cause error.

After `die ("Database query failed.");` remove `;` it can give you an error if you forget it and write other code.